# Move and Rename Python Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, move

I am making a text based game in python and want the character to be able to equip weapons. I have two dictionaries storing them like this (esword is equipped sword):

```
esword = {
}

swords = {
        'wooden_sword': {'name': 'Wooden Sword', 'dmg': 1},
        'stone_sword' : {'name': 'Stone Sword', 'dmg': 2},
        'gold_sword': {'name': 'Gold Sword', 'dmg': 2.5}
}
```

I want the character to be able to equip a sword, which involves moving it into the esword (and not removing it from swords dictionaries probably using `.copy()`) dictionary and renaming it to 'equippedsword' so that I can call it with `esword['equippedsword'][somekey]` .

The game is similar to a dice rolling game and adds the swords attack as shown:

`yourRollSword = (yourRoll + esword['equipped']['dmg'])`

So I basically just want a way to get the keys from the equipped swords dictionary.

Comment: They are dictionaries, not lists, and your question is not very clear.

Comment: Please read about [the xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and improve your question.

Comment: @Selcuk, sorry, how can I make it more clear?

Comment: Do you want the equipped sword to be removed from the `swords` dictionary? And can you clarify what exactly what your goal is (perhaps reword it to relate to the title of the question)?

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: @AlexHawking Not much. I, for myself, have no idea what the question is. Maybe posting some relevant parts of the code you've already written could help.

Comment: @selcuk, thanks for sticking with me, I'll add some code :)

Comment: @AlexHawking No worries. Also check the answer posted to see if it helps.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's probably a bad idea to organize the data this way (needing to move the object between two lists when equipped and unequpped). Why not just have a list of equipped swords referenced by key, then do a look-up into the swords dictionary? This is a non-destructive way to deal with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do an assignment like this:

```
sword_type = input("Which type of sword?")
esword[sword_type] = swords[sword_type]
```

If they later drop that weapon, you can do

```
dropped_sword = 'stone_sword'
del esword[dropped_sword]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine it could be something like this:

```
esword = swords['wooden_sword']
del swords['wooden_sword']
```

this will remove the sword from the dictionary of "all swords owned by the character" and assign it to the `esword` variable.

Answer (score 1):

could make a function

```
def equip(sword,swords):
    esword = swords[sword]
    return esword

esword = equip('gold_sword',swords)
```